# Speech_Recognition engine timeout (python 3.7.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I'm trying to implement speech recognition and response in python in a school project. Can't figure out what's wrong with my code:

Code: (Imports `speech_recognition as sr`)

```
def takeCommand():
    # It takes microphones recognition from the user and returns String output
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 0.8
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
        print(f"User said:{query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)
        print("Say that again please")
        return "None"
    return query
```

It stops response after `print('Listening...')` statement.

Traceback (On keyboard interruption):

```
Listening...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Yash Khandelwal/Desktop/Python_Files/Jarvis/Jarvis_Project.py", line 51, in <module>
    takeCommand()
  File "c:/Users/Yash Khandelwal/Desktop/Python_Files/Jarvis/Jarvis_Project.py", line 36, in takeCommand
    audio = r.listen(source)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 652, in listen    
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 161, in read      
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "C:\Users\New User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Is this easily solvable?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the pause threshold and use:

```
audio = r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
r.pause_threshold = 0.8
```

and try this one instead:

```
r.listen(source,timeout=2)
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try
query = r.recognize_google(audio,language='En-In')

or

query = r.recognize_google(audio)

it worked for me